# The argument to $each in $push must be an array but it was of type Object

Tags: mongodb-query

I want to add the element in array but in my document conation one `object :_id` in that I have another filed xxxxx in that list I want to add

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5cf261718c81f028sd73b2f9")
"college" : {
        "clzName" : "VDA",
        "clzList" : [],
        "List" : [],
        "place" : [],
        "date" : [ 
            "college"
        ]
    },

    db.getCollection('aaa').update({"_id" : ObjectId("5cf261718c81f028db73b2f9")},
       {$push:{"colllege":{$each:{"List":["dsd","jaa"]}}}})
```

e argument to `$each` in `$push` must be an array but it was of type Object

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work,

```
db.getCollection('aaa').update({"_id" : ObjectId("5cf261718c81f028db73b2f9")},
   {$push:{"colllege":{$each:[["List":["dsd","jaa"]]]}}})
```

It will insert it like this

```
"college":{
    [
     "List":[
       "dsd",
       "jaa"
      ]
    ]
}
```